# Define a method to filter items from list by Type

Tags: scala, types

I'm trying to filter a list by the type of items. The working code is here:

```
trait Action

class AAA extends Action
class BBB extends Action

val list = List(new AAA, new BBB, new AAA)

def find[T <: Action] = list.filter(_.isInstanceOf[T])

find[AAA]
```

It doesn't work as expected, see the output:

```
scala> def find[T <: Action] = list.filter(_.isInstanceOf[T])
<console>:11: warning: abstract type T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       def find[T <: Action] = list.filter(_.isInstanceOf[T])
                                                     ^
find: [T <: Action]=> List[Action]

scala> find[AAA]
res0: List[Action] = List(AAA@2b9cbeec, BBB@3fba8e52, AAA@70d5ca2d)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ClassTag`:

```
def find[T <: Action : ClassTag] =
  list.filter{ implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass.isInstance }

scala> find[AAA]
res0: List[Action] = List(AAA@145332ca, AAA@135cfef8)
```

It would be better to use `collect` method:

```
list.collect{ case e: AAA => e }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `implicit m:scala.reflect.Manifest[T]`

```
def find[T <: Action](implicit m:scala.reflect.Manifest[T]) = 
     list.filter{x:Any => m.erasure.isInstance(x)}.asInstanceOf[List[T]]
```

Comment: `erasure` is deprecated since version `2.10.0`.